# Grep key-value pairs where key name is equal to value name

Tags: grep

I am looking for a way to find key-value pairs where the key name equals the value name using find and grep or some equivalent command line tool avaliable in Linux, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -exec grep ... {} +
```

Matches to find (among others):

```
<video autoplay=autoplay loop=loop muted=muted playsinline=playsinline>
```

**Background:**

I am using [harpjs](https://harpjs.com/) for my website. Unfortunately, jade code like the following gets compiled to html code with key-value pairs where the key name equals the value name. This leads to problems, for example, in iOS Safari, where the the controls are shown in the html5 background video.

```
video(autoplay, loop, muted, playsinline)
```

**Update:**

I decided to approach the problem another way by analysing the jade code instead of the compiled html code. AFAIK, the following commands cover all cases where jade code might lead to html attributes with value names equal to attribute names:

```
# matches "(autoplay, "
find harp/public -type f -iname "*.jade" -exec grep --color '([a-zA-Z]*, ' \{\} +

# matches ", loop,"
find harp/public -type f -iname "*.jade" -exec grep --color ', [a-zA-Z]*,' \{\} +

# matches ", playsinline)"
find harp/public -type f -iname "*.jade" -exec grep --color ', [a-zA-Z]*)' \{\} +

# matches "(loop)"
find harp/public -type f -iname "*.jade" -exec grep --color '([a-zA-Z])' \{\} +
```

Comment: post a testable input file content

Comment: There's not a good way to do this with grep or any regular expressions. But the most common thing to do is something like: `'<tagName.*([^>]+)>'` (use sed) then you can go from there with splitting by whitespace or maybe with `=`. You really should use an HTML parser in another language (like BeatifulSoup in Python).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you do not give sufficient examples for your test cases. However, I've tried to provide a helpful solution based on the one test case you did give.

The following 'grep' command finds the substring containing non whitespace, non "<" ">" characters. The output of grep is then piped to awk which splits this result into a pair of strings separated by the character "=". Finally, the awk command then tests if each string either side of "=" is the same, and if it is, prints out the result:

```
grep -o '[^ |<]*=[^ |^>]*' test.txt | awk '{{split($0,a,"=")}; if (a[1] == a[2]) {print a[1];} }'
```

With test case 'test.txt':

```
<video autoplay=autoplay loop=loop muted=muted playsinline=playsinline>
```